# How can I update the value of an array in Local Storage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

The local storage object I have is something like this below:
Fruits                    {"cartitem1":"banana","cartitem2":"apple","cartitem3":"strawberry"}

I would like to only change cartitem3 fruit from "strawberry" to "pineapple" when cartitem3 selected item is changed by the user. Rest of the things should stay same upon refresh. How would I accomplish that?
I have something like this below to

const [fruits, setfruits] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("Fruits");
    console.log(localStorage)
    if (data) {
        setfruits(JSON.parse(data));
    }

}, []);
useEffect(() => {

    localStorage.setItem("Fruits", JSON.stringify(fruits));
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the array from localStorage , you would make changes on it and set it again.

```
const fruits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Fruits"));
const modifiedArray = fruits.filter(fruit => {
  
   if(fruit["cartitem"] === "strawberry"){
     fruit["cartitem"] = "pineapple"
   }
});

localStorage.setItem("Fruits", JSON.stringify(modifiedArray))
```

I think something like this script would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => { 
    const data =  !localStorage.getItem('Fruits') 
                      ? []
                      : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Fruits'))
  
   data['cartitem3']= 'pineapple'
   localStorage.setItem('Fruits', JSON.stringify(data))

    this.setState({Fruits: !localStorage.getItem('data') 
                      ? []
                      : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))
              })

    
  
}
```